# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn value member keeps reverting to (none) [VS2010]

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridviewcombobox, valuemember

I'm trying to set the ValueMember property on a ComboBox column of a DataGridView, from the designer in VS2010.

Every time I set the value, at the moment of leaving the cell, it revert to (none).

Same thing happens with the DisplayMember property.

Googled it and found nothing :(

[image]

Comment: You don't happen to be debugging are you? Most designers dont work while debugging.

Comment: No, I'm not in runtime debugging. Just to let you know, I can edit every other value but ValueMember and DisplayMember.

Comment: Setting these props from code also works! But I still do not understand why I can't set them in the designer.